# Set different highlight-line color for emacs --no-window

Tags: highlighting, term

How can I set a different color if I am using emacs on terminal (emacs --no-window)?

I use a grey highlight line when using emacs with GUI because my background theme is white. Here is the code I use in my `~/.emacs`.

```
(global-hl-line-mode +1)                                                                                                                      
(set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil :inherit nil :background "#e6ffff")
```

However, when I am using emacs on terminal it has a default black background and this highlight colour looks awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You detect your window sytem with `window-system`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795451/how-to-detect-that-emacs-is-in-terminal-mode).

In terminal mode this variable is `nil`, so you can change the face in this case.

```
(when (not window-system)
    (set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil :inherit nil :background "#888888"))
```